# What type of AI makes choices without considering the future?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

In other words, what type of AI makes a decision based solely on what the current state of the game is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can an AI know the real future? It can only have an imperfect model of it, and at most make predictions (which are not the same as the future itself). And your question is off-topic (and too broad), since unrelated to source code....

Comment: You don't need to know the future to consider it...

There is a name for a type of AI that does not anticipate the future whatsoever. There is absolutely no planning whatsoever in this AI strategy. I don't think this question is off topic, and I think you could at least try to be more helpful rather than dismissing my question entirely.

Comment: [markovian processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process) are not AI...

Comment: Read carefully: this AI does not consider the future whatsoever. It is far from a markovian process, as it does not try to determine the future as I've said before. I can assure you that I am talking about a legitimate branch of AI that is taught in college.

Comment: Then please name it. I can't guess what you mean. [neural network software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network_software)  or what?

Comment: An algorithm never considers anything. It's just a recipe for manipulating symbols, without knowing what they mean. The symbols (variables, values, data structures) only make sense to the human observer. And the human who creates the algorithm will always have to consider future states, even if the final algorithm is just a look up table for Tic-Tac-Toe moves. In a nutshell: unless you explain what you mean by "considers the future", the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the strictest sense of the word and the question, a pure reflex agent might satisfy the conditions.  A reflex agent chooses an action solely based on the previous percept or on its current model of the world, so depending on what you consider "considering" to be, that might fit the bill.

However, that really stretches the point far past breaking, in my opinion.

An agent in an MDP setting, running a policy for that setting, might be said to be making its decisions only based on the state without consideration of the future.  But that only begs the question:  Where did that policy come from?  It came, obviously, from a careful probabilistic consideration of the future rewards for taking particular actions from particular states.  Or in other words, the algorithm of the agent might be "run this policy," but the algorithm of determining the policy and the future-orientation of the policy itself are where the actual intelligence is.  We consider the agent to be intelligent by virtue of having determined that policy.

(And conceptually, the notion of reflex agents is really getting at the agent's treatment and consideration of the past, not the future.  What I say above is true in a technical sense, not an important philosophical sense.)

All AI in the planning domain is future-oriented, by definition.  If you're not at some level considering the results of your actions into the future, you're not an intelligent agent.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! A pure reflex agent was exactly what I was thinking of. I have one follow-up question, if you have a second.
I programmed a tic-tac-toe-like game where a player played a computer. I created an AI that considered only the current state when making a decision. The AI considered only the defensive and offensive value each location gave through analyzing the current board. I know basically nothing about formal AI, so my question is: how would I formally explain my simple AI? For example, would I say "I created a reflex-based AI"?

Comment: More info: the algorithm only counted the amount of x-in-a-row streaks it created for me and the amount of x-in-a-row streaks ended for the opponent.

Comment: If I had implemented a reflex-based agent, I would be very reluctant to describe it as an AI at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in decision problems under uncertainty, you can have a look at **influence diagrams**.

Otherwise the problem appears to reduce to an optimization problem, of which there are many different kinds:

- linear optimization
- constraint satisfcation
- convex optimization
- non-convex (or general) optimization
- ...